# Why is the result a recurring number when it should be an integer?

Tags: python, numpy

Hi so i'm writing some code for class and this for Linear Regression.
The values calculated by hand is a=1.7 and b=1.6 for the data you can see in the code.

I've tried separating different parts of the formula into different variables but the answer remains the same (1.6999999999999993).

```
import numpy as np  
x=np.array([2,3,5,6])  
y=np.array([4.5,7.2,9.2,11.5])  
b=(np.sum((y-np.mean(y))*x))/(np.sum((x-np.mean(x))*x))  
a=np.mean(y)-(b*(np.mean(x)))  
print(a)   
print(b)
```

The expected result is a=1.7 and b=1.6, but the output is a=1.6999999999999993.

Comment: 1.7 isn't an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using `float` number, binary floating point math is like this. In most programming languages, it is based on the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats).

see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats).

But if you want your result in the form of 'a=1.7'. Then you can try this..

```
import numpy as np  
x=np.array([2,3,5,6])  
y=np.array([4.5,7.2,9.2,11.5])  
b=(np.sum((y-np.mean(y))*x))/(np.sum((x-np.mean(x))*x))  
a=np.mean(y)-(b*(np.mean(x)))  
a = "%.1f"% (a)
print(a)   
print(b)
```